# git stuck at checking out files when cloning a specific branch

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I need to clone a specific branch from a GitLab project. I've been trying git extension and command line but neither works. Both methods stuck at checking out files with 37% progress. Cloning the project is fine but every time I tried checking out the branch I needed it would ALWAYS stuck at 37%. What should I do?

I've been using git clone -b branch repo. It just ends at "Checking out files: 37% (xxxxxx/xxxxxx)". Actually it stuck there over 2 days when I tried last week.

Comment: Is the command line giving you any further information, such as an error message? Can you also let us know which command exactly you are executing?

Comment: I've been using git clone -b branch repo. The command line just ends at "Checking out files:  37% (141690/380218)". Actually it stuck there over 2 days when I tried last week.

Comment: Are you using something in addition to Git, such as Git-LFS?

Comment: Curious. The clone operation does all the cloning part first, and then at the end, creates the branch and checks out the commit. It's that last step that's hanging up, and there's no obvious reason it would do so.

Comment: I suggest to clone with `--no-checkout`, then you can investigate the checkout problem without having to download the repo again.

Comment: Hi @torek sorry I didn’t realizeI had been using git -LFS. The issue still exits. Do you think this can be something related to git lfs?

Comment: Definitely. With Git-LFS, Git itself doesn't store certain files (any that you've selected, usually "large" files). Instead, Git stores tiny little files that contain information that Git-LFS, a piece of add-on software, uses *during* `git checkout`. At that time, LFS sneaks in and says "oh, this little file, don't use that, I've got the real one here". LFS reaches out to the large-file-server (which is NOT Git) and downloads the real file and puts that in, instead. But depending on your LFS server, download speeds, and file sizes, this could take hours or days.

Comment: If it *is* taking days, you probably have a slow link and/or extremely large (multi-gigabyte or terabyte) files ... or, something else is broken so that LFS thinks the file is coming through, but it isn't really. So you'll want to debug that part, which means asking on a Git-LFS tag how to debug Git-LFS downloads.